# I have all Phone apps. But I do not have the Phone Icon Anywhere

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have all Phone Apps, but I do not see my Phone Icon Anywhere.
How Can I Put my "PHONE" Icon Short cut back on Tray?

Answer (score 0):

For All those who had the same problem, when an Icon goes missing on your tray or anywhere else, I found a solution.
1)- Download "ES File Manager" From Google Play and Install it.
2)- Go to Apps and select System Apps
3)- Either Find or search for the App you need 
4)- Long Press on it and it will become selected
5)- From the Option button Select "Add to Desktop"

The App short cut appears again on the desktop. Now you simply drag it to wherever you want.

Comment: Note: ES has not the best reputation lately. Have you checked your app drawer before? Isn't the phone app listed there? Because if it is, you could simply tap-and-hold it there, and then let it drop on your homescreen. That's how app icons are added to the homescreen usually.

Comment: +1 what Izzy said. Also, please [accept your own answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).